# Multiple Angular Reactive forms and one service that depends on them all

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am essentially trying to replicate spreadsheet behavior.  I have several reactive forms, each of which deals with a specific section of the overall calculation.  And some inputs affect the value of others.  To simplify, take this example.

Form A has loan information, including an interest rate. Form B has bank information including that loan payment.  Form C shows totals for various categories of expenses (not just loans).  When the rate changes in A, I need to update the loan payment in B which will update the totals in C.

If that was all, I think my solution would be straight-forward.  However, the catch is that I have a service to handle the shared calculations. Each form calculates its own totals and passes those totals to the service. The service does "the main calculation" and patches the reactive forms.

So Form A changes, triggering the "valueChanges" event, which triggers the service's main calculation.  The main calculation updates totals in C and fields in form B. Now B needs to recalculate its subtotals. When B is done with its subtotals, the service's main calculation needs to run again to update C.  The astute of you will have picked up on the infinite loop that lies ahead if I don't use:

```
{ emitEvent: false }
```

with my patchValues call.

I'm new to reactive forms and the concept of keeping the form and the data separated.  This is easy to do when the service has all of the fields and I use ngModel for the inputs; change the service, change the form.

I'm hoping someone who is an expert with this data decoupling paradigm will shine some light on how I can achieve my objective.  I would accept a completely new approach if needed.  The idea, again, is basically to replicate spreadsheet functionality with modular data sections (allowing Banking info, expenses, and totals to maintain their autonomy).

Per request, I've added some of the code.

```
/*  When any form changes, it updates the service
It then triggers the calculate function so that the relevant fields are 
updated.
*/

/* Form A */
onFormChange() {
    const formVals = this.loanForm.getRawValue(); // one of the values is the loan rate
    this.calcSubTotals(); // adds up the relevant fields in each loan. 
    for(const formFieldKey of Object.keys(formVals)) {
        this.calculationService[formFieldKey] = formVals[formFieldKey]
    }
    this.calculationService.calculate();
}

/* Form B */
onFormChange() {
    const formVals = this.bankForm.getRawValue();
    this.calcSubTotals(); // adds up the fields in each account. One of those fields is a loan payment that is updated by the service
    for(const formFieldKey of Object.keys(formVals)) {
        this.calculationService[formFieldKey] = formVals[formFieldKey]
    }
    this.calculationService.calculate();
}
/* Form C - Summary */
onFormChange() {
    const formVals = this.summaryForm.getRawValue();
    // I won't break this down as it doesn't have any calcuated values
    // however, it does show allCosts which is updated by the calculation service
    for (const formFieldKey of Object.keys(formVals)) {
        this.calculationService[formFieldKey] = formVals[formFieldKey]
    }
    this.calculationService.calculate();
}

/* Calculation Service */
calculate() {
    // Various calculations occcur here
    // All calcuations use the values of the service...not the individual forms
    // one of the values that is modified here is payment
    const loanPayment = ...; // math here to get the loanPayment
    const allCosts = ...; // this is the tricky part. I;m summing all of the subtotals
    this.bankForm.patchValues({
        loanPayment: calculatedLoanPayment // the other tricky part.  loanPayment affects the subtotal which has already been used above
    }, {emitEvent: false});
    this.summaryForm.patchValues({
        allCosts: calculatedAllCosts;
    });
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: No service should ever have knowledge of a form to be patching a form value.

Comment: can you add some code so that we can help ?

Comment: in abstract, I'll try that the service return, not only the data that must be changed in A, also data in B and C and make severals setValue using {emitEvent:false} with each data

Comment: @AdrianBrand, I mentioned that I am new to reactive forms. How do I work with data in a reactive form if a service shouldn't patch a form?  I needed to use a service because I have several forms that need to share data with one another. My question is essentially what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @CruelEngine, the code I have so far is very simple.  The excerpts above are all that is done in the forms. The calculation function in the service is the only one that deals with forms. I only left out the details of the calculations. Those are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply comparing the new values to the old for each module.  If the values changed, I emitted the change event. If not, I don't.  It's pretty straight-forward, but I"m not sure if this is the best way because I still end up running some code that feels useless, but it works.

New workflow:
* Form A changes - triggers calculation service
* Calc service recalculates and emits change
* Form A, B, and C respond by comparing old values to new
  - Case A: Form A is changed by calc service: it emits change which triggers calc again
    ~ Calc recalculates and emits change
    ~ Form A, B, and C respond again, but now there is no change. (this is the code that seems "useless" to me...or "extra".
    ~ End
  - Case B: no forms are changed:
    ~ End

This only works because there are no circular references in the calculations. Which is fine, because no spreadsheet would allow for that either.